# Checking number of markers shown on visible region android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I am working on map app where I am getting the co-ordinates of the places from my server and I am calling the API which get me the co-ordinates from server using  `mMap.setOnCameraIdleListener`. The problem is that the API is being called every time I move the camera and markers are being set on the same position again and again if user has just slightly move the map camera.

Now, I thought of checking the number of markers on the visible region, but I am not getting how to count the number of markers only on visible region.
I used the below code but it only can tell me if one specific `LatLng` point is visible on the visible region or not.

```
public boolean isVisibleOnMap(LatLng latLng) {
    VisibleRegion vr = mMap.getProjection().getVisibleRegion();
    return vr.latLngBounds.contains(latLng);
}
```

Comment: Try using a for loop to reiterate over all markers and use vr.latLngBounds.contains(latLng); to check if these markers are contained in the visible region. This is a duplicate of your same [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38896671/getting-number-of-markers-of-visible-region-of-google-maps-android) where the answer, though written in JS, suggested using loops.

Comment: Thanks it helps me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am posting this as an answer:

Try using a for loop to reiterate over all markers and use `vr.latLngBounds.contains(latLng);` to check if these markers are contained in the visible region.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(mMap.getProjection().getVisibleRegion().latLngBounds.contains(currentMarker.getPosition())){
//Showing in VisibleRegion
} else {
//Not Showing
}
```