# Getting Number of Markers of visible region of google maps android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

How can we calculate the number of those markers shown on the visible region only on google maps android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var markers; //your markers
var map; //your map
var countInBoundingBox = 0; //the counter for the markers in bounding box

for (var i = markers.length, bounds = map.getBounds(); i--;) {
  if (bounds.contains(markers[i].getPosition())) {
    countInBoundingBox++;
  }
}
```

Next time try to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). :-)